# Time complexity(Big-O) for nested hash-map

Tags: java, data-structures, hashmap, big-o

For the assignment which was to implement the submission history, it required me to use data structure for each methods and it needs to be better than O(n). So I used nested hash-map(map of maps),

```
HashMap<String, TreeMap<Object, Object>>()
```

Because, the following methods take less than O(n):

1. getBestGrade: find all submission for student in O(1) and then find best submission in O(N) (it can be improved by caching best score).
2. getSubmissionFinal: find all submission for student in O(1) and then find last in O(1)
3. getSubmissionBefore: find all submission for student in O(1) and then find result in O(1)
4. add: find or add submissions for student in O(1) and then add submission in O(log(N)) (if you implement caching you should update cache here)
5. remove find or add submissions for student in O(1) and then remove submission in O(log(N)) (if you implement caching you should update cache here)

However, what I am concerning about is, someone told me that its worst-case is O(n) so it should not be used, on the other hand, the teacher said that, it does take O(n) for the worst-case, however, it is usually more sensible to perform the analysis using the expected case, O(1). And this would need to be justified briefly in the report when using the nested hash-map with tree-map in it.

So, what I know so far is that, its worst-case is O(n) but there is low possibility because the hash-map`s size also grows in the current Java implementation(I do not even feel sure of it...)

The main question is, why is it more sensible for the expected case, not the worst-case?

I have not enough information to explain why the nested hash-map above is better than O(n) for the methods I mentioned above. I searched up for it but could not find the result that I was looking for... I would be very thankful if someone can get rid of my confusion towards my question... Thanks.

Comment: What is this map of maps supposed to represent, in the real world?  You never told us this.  Nevermind...I think the outer key is a student and the corresponding map the submissions.  From what I see, you are already done because the operations you describe would match the performance of a `TreeMap`.

Comment: sorry I didnt get that, can you tell me what I need to add more?

Comment: ah yeap thats right, sorry for that. Oh is it?

Comment: I am also confused on explaining the nested map. Should I split the two maps and explain one by one?

Comment: For example, hashmap takes O(1) for get and remove, and treemap takes O(log n) for remove, get and other functions?

Comment: Your explanation looks correct; a `TreeMap` would match those performance numbers.  What is your actual question?

Comment: The main question is, why is it more sensible for the expected case, not the worst-case?

Comment: @승기유 because the expected case will happen way more often, so in practice you can expect O(1) performance

Answer (score 0):

> However, what I am concerning about is, someone told me that its worst-case is O(n) so it should not be used

He is wrong.

> on the other hand, the teacher said that, it does take O(n) for the worst-case, however, it is usually more sensible to perform the analysis using the expected case, O(1).

He is correct. It is conventional to treat hash maps as *O(1)*. The *O(N)* case arises so rarely that it is unrealistic to include it in the generalized computational complexity.

> And this would need to be justified briefly in the report when using the nested hash-map with tree-map in it.

Not if he already told you it is so. You've been so instructed. You can assume it. Everybody else does. All you need to show is that the nested hashmaps are *O(1)* because *O(1)* squared is still *O(1)*, and the hashmap/treemap case is *O(log(N))* because *O(1)* multiplied by *O(log(N))* is still *O(log(N))*.